# Filter or map nodelists in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, nodelist

What is the most efficient way to filter or map a nodelist in ES6?

Based on my readings, I would use one of the following options:

```
[...nodelist].filter
```

or

```
Array.from(nodelist).filter
```

Which one would you recommend? And are there better ways, for example without involving arrays?

Comment: Basically, both methods do the same thing. It you're using `babel`, then `[...coll]` will simply call `Array.from(coll)` for anything that is not an `Array`.

Comment: FWIW, `...` syntax may be unsupported by older IDEs while `Array.from()` is just a regular method.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

- `[...nodelist]` will make an array of out of an object if the object is iterable.
- `Array.from(nodelist)` will make an array out of an object if the object is iterable *or* if the object is array-like (has `.length` and numeric props)

Your two examples will be identical if `NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` exists, because both cases cover iterables. If your environment has not been configured such that `NodeList` is iterable however, your first example will fail, and the second will succeed. `Babel` currently [does not handle this case properly](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2160).

So if your `NodeList` is iterable, it is really up to you which you use. I would likely choose on a case-by-case basis. One benefit of `Array.from` is that it takes a second argument of a mapping function, whereas the first `[...iterable].map(item => item)` would have to create a temporary array, `Array.from(iterable, item => item)` would not. If you are not mapping the list however, it does not matter.

Comment: Just note that `Array.from` isn't support on IE.

Comment: @YannDìnendal That's true, but this question is asking about ES6, and IE doesn't support ES6 at all pretty much, so already a dead end.

Comment: Yes it's true. :) I should have clarified what I meant: if you rely on Babel to transpile es6 to es5, it will not by default polyfill prototype methods. So just something to be aware of. :)

Comment: Is this better or worse than `Array.prototype.map.call(nodelist, fn)` ? (I'm curious if `map.call` is more performant, and "most efficient" is part of the question. Although I'm aware that 'efficien' is not the same as 'performant'.)

Answer (score 24):

I found a [reference](https://tiffanybbrown.com/2012/10/16/iterating-and-applying-functions-to-nodelists-with-map-and-foreach/index.html) that uses `map` directly on the NodeList by

```
Array.prototype.map.call(nodelist, fn)
```

I haven't tested it, but it seems plausible that this would be faster because it should access the NodeList directly.

Comment: It is even easier then that: `NodeList.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map`

Answer (score 21):

TL;DR;

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist).filter
```

The slice() method returns an array.
That returned array is a shallow copy of collection (NodeList)
<strike>So it works faster than **Array.from()**</strike>
So it works as fast as **Array.from()**

Elements of the original collection are copied into the returned array as follows:

- For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.
- For strings, numbers and booleans (not String, Number and Boolean objects), slice copies the values into the new array. Changes to the string, number or boolean in one array do not affect the other array.

**Short explanation regarding arguments**

Array.prototype.slice(beginIndex, endIndex)

- takes optional args beginIndex and endIndex.
  If they are not provided slices uses beginIndex == 0, thus it extracts all the items from the collection

Array.prototype.slice.call(namespace, beginIndex, endIndex)

- takes an object as the first argument. If we use a collection as an object it literally means that we call slice method directly from that object **namespace.slice()**

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I'm wondering if this has IE support since `Array.from` does not. Time to find an IE machine. Now I'm really confused because I was able to use Array.from in IE10 and IE11 :\. This method does work in IE10+11 but I am not eased by Array.from working when all documentation says otherwise.

Comment: `Array.from` does not work for me in IE11 _Object doesn't support property or method 'from'_

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on an old implementation of JavaScript

Comment: `Array.from` also returns a shallow copy. So I don't see how you **conclude** that it works faster than `Array#slice`.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your comment, I've updated my answer

Comment: *Wondering why not just `Array.slice()`?* it's because `slice` is not a "class" function but a prototype function of the future `Array` object `[]` unlike e.g. `Array.isArray()` which is a "class"(something like a "static") function and can be called directly on `Array`. Therefore there actually is no `Array.slice`, only **`Array.prototype.slice`** :)

Answer (score 8):

### `[...a].filter` vs `Array.from(a).filter`

Not a "real" difference in performance, `Array.from` could be a very very  tiny bit faster because you're not creating a new `Array` on the "JS level", but it happens directly in the native code.

### Performance - consider *not* using *either*

However for **performance** (and to also avoid "`Array`-ing") you should consider **why** are you filtering  a `NodeList` and **where/how** did you get it. In many cases, you just want a particular element either by `id` or by `class` or other CSS selector.

`document.querySelectorAll` is like **10x - 200x faster** and works for any CSS selector

`document.getElementById` is even faster (but of course requires an `id`)

You can even optimize `querySelectorAll` or bypass "not-yet-known" case if you provide a pre-stored parent to look in, let me give you an example:

```
let mainbar = document.getElementById('mainbar');
mainbar.querySelectorAll('.flex--item');
```

**is almost 10x faster than**

```
Array.from(a).filter(el => el.classList.contains("flex--item"))
```

Also be aware that `document.querySelectorAll('#mainbar .flex--item');` is still about 5x faster than `Array` filtering, but about 2x slower than pre-storing the parent with an `id`.

#### Besides better performance, you **will also always get `NodeList`** (it may be empty, but it still will be `NodeList`) and that goes for both [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```js
// Be evil. Extend the prototype.
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.filter) {
  NodeList.prototype.filter = Array.prototype.filter;
}

// Use it like you'd expect:
const noClasses = document
  .querySelectorAll('div')
  .filter(div => div.classList.length === 0)
```

It's the same approach as mentioned in [the MDN docs for NodeList.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) (under 'Polyfill'), it **works for IE11**, Edge, Chrome and FF.

Comment: slight warning, now nodeList.filter will then give you an array instead of a node list. shouldn't be a problem, but easy to forget ^^

Answer (score 2):

> **Filter or map nodelists in ES6**
> I came out of this simple function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/NodeList/entries#exemple

```
function filterNodeList(NodeList, callback) {
            if (typeof callback !== "function") callback = (i) => i; // Any better idea?
            const Result = document.createElement("div");
            
    //# No need to filter empty NodeList
            if (NodeList.length === 0) return NodeList;
        
            for (let i = 0; i < NodeList.length; i++) {
              if (callback(NodeList.item(i))){
                 Result.appendChild(NodeList.item(i));
                 i--; //If you don't want to clone
              }
            }
            return Result.childNodes;
     }
```

Comment: To kip the elements in the DOM, you can clone them and kip referencies Result.appendChild(NodeList.item(i).cloneNode). Next before you work on them, you just have to go back and say dom, give me this type of node with this attribut :: Important! Node === NodeList....

Comment: You need to clone the node or decrement `i` in the `appendChild` call or the code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Using ECMAS 2016:

```
let nodes = [...document.querySelector('__SELECTOR__').childNodes].filter(item => item.nodeType === 1);
```