# Selecting a childnode by inner text from a NodeList

Tags: javascript, dom, filtering, nodelist

First part [solved]

Given this HTML

```html
    <div id="search_filters">
     <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something</p><ul>...</ul></section>
     <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something1</p><ul>...</ul></section>
     <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something2</p><ul>...</ul></section>
     <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something3</p><ul>...</ul></section>
     <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something4</p><ul>...</ul></section>
    </div>
```

I can select all the section with

`const select = document.querySelectorAll('section[class^="facet clearfix"]');`

The result is a nodelist with 5 children.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to select only the *section* containing the "something3" string.

This is my first attempt:

```
`const xpathResult = document.evaluate( //section[p[contains(.,'something3')]],
        select,  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

How can I filter the selection to select only the *node* I need?

Second part:

Sorry for keeping update the question but it seems this is a problem out of my actual skill..
Now that i get the Node i need to work in what i've to do it's to set a custom order of the li in the  sections:

```
<ul id="" class="collapse">
  <li>
   <label>
    <span>
     <input>
      <span>
       <a> TEXT
       </a>
      </span>
     </input>
    </span>
   </label>
  </li>
<li>..</li>
```

Assuming there are n

with n different texts and i've a custom orders to follow i think the best way to go it would be look at the innertex and matching with an array where i set the correct order.

```
var sorOrder = ['text2','text1','text4','text3']
```

Comment: can you loop over the `select` list?

Comment: I edited a bit what i need to achieve because probably before wasnt that clear

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach should lead you to the solution.
Giving your HTML

```html
<div id="search_filters">
 <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something</p><ul>...</ul></section>
 <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something1</p><ul>...</ul></section>
 <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something2</p><ul>...</ul></section>
 <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something3</p><ul>...</ul></section>
 <section class="facet clearfix"><p>something4</p><ul>...</ul></section>
</div>
```

I would write this js

```js
const needle = "something3";
const selection = document.querySelectorAll('section.facet.clearfix');
let i = -1;

console.info("SELECTION", selection);
let targetIndex;
while(++i < selection.length){
  if(selection[i].innerHTML.indexOf(needle) > -1){
    targetIndex = i;
  }
}
console.info("targetIndex", targetIndex);
console.info("TARGET", selection[targetIndex]);
```

Then you can play and swap elements around without removing them from the DOM.

PS. Since you know the CSS classes for the elements you don't need to use the `^*` (start with) selector. I also improved that.

**PART 2: ordering children li based on content**

```js
const ul = selection[targetIndex].querySelector("ul"); // Find the <ul>
const lis = ul.querySelectorAll("li"); // Find all the <li>
const sortOrder = ['text2', 'text1', 'text4', 'text3'];
i = -1; // We already declared this above
while(++i < sortOrder.length){
    const li = [...lis].find((li) => li.innerHTML.indexOf(sortOrder[i]) > -1);
    !!li && ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

This will move the elements you want (only the one listed in `sortOrder`) in the order you need, based on the content and the position in `sortOrder`.

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/tonysamperi/pen/LYYpjQb)

Comment: Thanks you! i got exactly the section i need to work on, now i've to make a custom orders.. If i'm going to ecounter any problems could i ask u?

Comment: Thank you for keep trying to help me find a way to code it!
Right now it's giving me this error : 
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

Comment: I just tried the code in the answer. It works just fine! Refresh the page, I think you're not getting the last version (I made some edits once a while)

Comment: Actually it could be that the `find` returns `undefined`. That would mean that the innerHTML doesn't contain the string you're searching.
I made an edit, to prevent that kind of error (`undefined` would not be of type `Node`)

Comment: Really impressive! It worked!
If i can i would like to ask you one more thing for improving my knowledge. If instead of ordering this with a custom order i order this in desc numerical way (assuming the strings have words and numbers) what should i change?
Ex.
1) abs 200-201
2)grehgrhr 203-204
3)abs-ege 202
it should give me back this -->
1)grehgrhr 203-204
2)abs-ege 202
3)abs 200-201
U've been really helpfull anyway!
I really appreciate ur effort, Thanks!

Comment: Ok first of all you should mark my answer as solution, by clicking the "check" symbol on the left.
What you're asking is a bit long to achieve. I think you should post another question.
I will help you with that!

Answer (score 0):

You can get that list filtered as:

- DOM Elements:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section[class^="facet clearfix"]')).filter(_ => _.querySelector('p').innerText === "something3")
```

- HTML Strings:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section[class^="facet clearfix"]')).filter(_ => _.querySelector('p').innerText === "something3").map(_ => _.outerHTML)
```

:)

Comment: i tried your code but if i try to 
console.log it gave me "undefined" instead of "<section class="facet clearfix"><p>something3</p><ul>...</ul></section>" but maybe i wanst so clear in my questions

Comment: Are you looking to get a filtered list of results, or just remove them from the DOM? This code actually removes them from the DOM.

Comment: ok so probably I was misunderstood, i need to get a filtered list of results and not remove them from DOM..because after that i'll have to work and change the li orders.

Comment: Just edited the response, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a higher order function like filter on your nodelist, you have to change it to an array. You can do this by destructering:

```
var select = document.querySelectorAll('section[class^="facet clearfix"]');

const filtered = [...select].filter(section => section.children[0].innerText == "something3")
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765157/filter-or-map-nodelists-in-es6#32767009) answer explains the magic behind it better.