# Iterate through array of paragraphs and add content from another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 `<p>` elements which I want to change dynamically.
I have values for those paragraphs in the array.

This is my HTML:

```
<p class="para">text xxx</p>
<p class="para">text yyy</p>
<p class="para">text zzz</p>
```

this is my JS:

```
var mobile = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 567px)")
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.para')
let paraText = [
  'text for mobile xxx',
  'text for mobile yyy',
  'text for mobile zzz'
]

if (mobile) {
  paragraphs.map(paragraph => {
    paragraph.innerText = '{belonging element from paraText}'
  })
}
```

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: So your issue is to pick right text from array for particular paragraph?

Comment: Map takes a second argument, the index of the iteration, which you could use to pull the corresponding element from the array. `paragraphs.map((paragraph, index) => paraText[index] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` not an Array, and therefore won't have the `map` function.

Additionally, `map` is used to create a new array based on an existing array, while your use case is about modifying other objects. `forEach` would be more appropriate here.

Instead, try either [converting the NodeList into an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765157/filter-or-map-nodelists-in-es6) :

```
if (mobile) {
  let paragraphsArray = [...paragraphs];
  paragraphsArray.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.innerText = paraText[i];
  })
}
```

or, simply iterate over `paraText` instead:

```
if (mobile) {
  paraText.forEach((text, i) => {
    paragraphs[i].innerText = text;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 567px)")) {
  const paraText = [
    'text for mobile xxx',
    'text for mobile yyy',
    'text for mobile zzz'
  ];

  document.querySelectorAll('.para')
    .forEach((p, i) => p.innerText = paraText[i]);
}
```